# Why does my Variable Audio Out not send a signal from my Toshiba 26AV500 TV?

Tags: home-studio, cable

I have a computer hooked up to a Toshiba 26AV500 TV with an HDMI cable.  The TV has a Variable Audio Out with RCA cords as well as a Digital Optical Audio-Out, that is hooked up to my amp (which is then connected to my studio monitors).   Neither the Digital Optical nor the Variable RCA outputs are sending any signal.

The signal is being lost between the TV and the amp.  I can plug the computer directly to the Amp, but the signal gets lost when I try to use the TV as an intermediary.

Since neither my amp, nor my computer has a remote control, I would like to be able to use the TV remote to control the volume of the studio monitors from different places in the room when I am mixing, without manually changing the volume on the amp.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Sorry, home electronics questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @BenV, even if the audio out is connected to the studio monitors I am using to mix with?  My objective was to use the TV remote to control the volume more easily, since I don't have a remote control for the amp

Comment: If you can edit to clarify that this is a home-studio question I'll re-open.  We just don't want to set a precedent for future questions.

Comment: @BenV, Please review my changes.

Comment: What kind of mixing situation is this if you don't mind adding a TV to the signal chain? I imagine that would just add noise and distortion and wouldn't really help much at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's because the internals of the TV don't link the audio input from the HDMI lead to the RCA output.  This is because it would require another DAC which most people wouldn't use.  As an example on my Samsung the RCA out will output TV, and any audio input on the scart sockets, but it won't give me audio from the HDMI input.

The easiest way to solve this would be to use a separate input on your amp for the PC, and then just switch between the inputs to have audio either from the TV or from the PC.  The other option, if you amp supports it is to link the HDMI lead through the amp.

Comment: The amp does not support HDMI.  Regarding the DAC issue, I have also updated my question to reflect that neither the Digital Optical output nor the RCA output are functional.

Comment: I can only guess that the internal routing of the TV doesn't allow output of digital sources on either analogue or digital outputs.  Maybe you can get remote for the PC that gives you a volume control.

Comment: It seems like the test to see if you are correct is to hook up an A/V source via an RCA input on the TV.  Since the source is analog and not digital, then if the issue is with converting digital sources to an output,  then the output should work...  Right?

Comment: Yes, in theory.  I know it works that way on my Samsung but it might be different on a Toshiba.

Answer (score 0):

Either by design or configuration, the audio coming in is not being routed out. If it's design there's nothing you can really do about it, but if it's configuration then the solution is of course to configure it, but it might not be clear exactly how to do that.

The first place I'd go to look would be the manual for the TV.